# How to circular import using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, circular-dependency

I have came up with a simple code where I cannot figure out why and how it can be solved with circular imports.

**test.py**

```
from test2 import specific_ID

store_name = "testing"
STORE_ID = specific_ID()
print(STORE_ID)
```

**test2.py**

```
from test import store_name

print(store_name)

def specific_ID():
    print("Yay works")
    print(f"Store name: {store_name}")
    return True
```

the idea is that when I have the variable `store_name` in `test.py`, I would like it to be a sort of "constant" value where I can re-use the value in `test2.py` - However it does not seems to like where it throws err:

```
from test2 import specific_ID
ImportError: cannot import name 'specific_ID' from partially initialized module 'test2' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

My question is, how is it possible to re-use a variable from test.py to test.py?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Circular imports should be avoided, just put both test.py and test2.py in a package and put their shared globals in the main namespace:

**__init__.py**

```
STORE_NAME = 'testing'
```

**test.py** and **test2.py**

```
from . import STORE_NAME
```

But you can circumvent the global variables all together:

**test2.py**

```
def specific_ID(store_name: str) -> int:
    "Return the ID for a store"
    print("Yay works")
    print(f"Store name: {store_name}")
    # lookup id
    return id
```

**test.py**

```
from test2 import specific_ID
    
store_name = "testing"
STORE_ID = specific_ID(store_name)
print(STORE_ID)
```

When your functions are pure functions, separate from global state, that makes them much easier to reason about and refactor.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much! I dont know why I haven't came up with the idea at all! That was pretty nice and well a good knowledge for my brain! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

TLDR: Since in test2.py you only need to reference the store_name variable, removing the import of specific_id and the code that references specific_id and the error should go away.

Long answer: A circular import error is caused in test.py by the line:

```py
from test2 import specific_ID
```

When python encounters this line, it will pause the execution of test.py, and attempt to process test2.py, so that it can get the value of the item that is being imported, which in this case is the specific_id function.

However, when we take a closer look at test2.py, we can see that at the top of the file, it is attempting to import from test.py:

```py
from test import store_name
```

Now, since we reached this point by Python pausing execution on test.py, it means that the variable `store_name` has not been processed by Python at all, and therefore test2.py is unable to import it from test.py, thus leading to a circular import error. In my opinion, it will be best for the files to look like this to remove the error:

**test.py**:

```py
store_name = "testing"
```

**test2.py**:

```py
from test import store_name

print(store_name)

def specific_ID():
    print("Yay works")
    print(f"Store name: {store_name}")
    return True

STORE_ID = specific_ID()
print(STORE_ID)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the description! Was very good to read and good knowledge to understand it more as well! I do appreciate the examples as well. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

The other two answers provide good advice on how to structure your code and why the error occurs. You should listen to them, because they show you the right way to do things. This answer is not about that. Instead, let's figure out the minimal set of changes that will let you make the import actually work.

**V1**

`test2` will import fine as long as `test` defines `store_name`. You can ensure that this happens by moving the import in `test` down one line:

```
store_name = "testing"

from test2 import specific_ID

STORE_ID = specific_ID()
print(STORE_ID)
```

**V2**

The opposite works too: the import of `test` will work fine as long as `test2` defines `specific_ID`. Two changes will allow this. One is to move the import after the function definition, since the names used in a function do not need to exist until you run it:

```
def specific_ID():
    print("Yay works")
    print(f"Store name: {store_name}")
    return True

from test import store_name

print(store_name)
```

Placing imports at the end is a "common" technique for dealing with circular imports. Common is in quotes because the problem is not actually all that common and is code smell to begin with. You shouldn't be fixing it like that to begin with.

**V2b**

The second option for `test2` is to perform the import inside the function. This is a more significant change because you also have to get rid of the print statement. Given how imports work, the import statement won't actually do anything besides create a local reference to the already-loaded module, so you don't have to worry about an expensive operation every time you run the function:

```
def specific_ID():
    from test import store_name

    print("Yay works")
    print(f"Store name: {store_name}")
    return True
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for the information. I do have a question. @Chris Wesseling had a example where he used `__init__` which two of the other answers including yours does not have it. I know maybe for this example there is no need for but is there any reason of e.g. not using the `__init__` compare to the examples that you have provided?

Comment: @ProtractorNewbie I don't know of any reason not to. In fact, often packages import the important things from their sub modules in the `__init__` so you can do `from package import important_thing` . See the [requests source](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/main/requests/__init__.py) for instance, it divides the code in modules like `api` and `exceptions`, but import their important objects into `__init__` so the package becomes easy to use and remember.

Comment: @ProtractorNewbie. Chris's answer might be more complex than what you need, but it's the right way to go. Kurois' answer is really suggesting that you should stick everything into one module, even if it's not stated explicitly. The general point is that you should not rely on global state in a function, and that you should keep your constants in a reasonable place. My answer, on the other hand, shows you what not to do :)

Comment: You can start with keeping things in one module. And if it becomes too big to handle, you can always turn the module into a package and split its components into separate modules for clarity. Just import the things that used to be in the original module in the `__init__` so other code that uses the module (now a package)  doesn't break. No need to pre-emptively make things more complex than they need to be. Being able to reason about the code is what's most important.

Comment: @ChrisWesseling the only idea I have in my mind is that I will later do a call from my database where I will receive an ID and I want to declare it to a variable which I want to share it to different files. I do see the importing from `__init__` to be a easy task to do but if its pyhonotic correct. Thats what I am afraid if its not :( Its not like anyone will see my code either way but I want to do it correct from the beginning :)

Comment: @ProtractorNewbie if you are afraid of re-doing expensive operations, then [functools.lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=lru_cache#functools.lru_cache) is your friend. It lets you trade time for memory. But that's a whole different topic :) have fun.